# Connecting to mongoDB using mongoose: neither on error nor once open are triggered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code is like:

```
try {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fl00ipflop', {useNewUrlParser: true});
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/get', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', function() {
    console.log("is error");
  });
  db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("is open");
  });
  var user_id = req.param('id');
  var token = req.param('token');
  var geo = req.param('geo');  
  res.send(user_id + ' ' + token + ' ' + geo);
});
```

I see nothing in console. Knowing I am running nodemon, although I think it has nothing altering the console;

I even set the code inside db.once and under it.

```
  var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
  var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);

  var small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
  small.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // saved!
  });

  // or

  Tank.create({ size: 'small' }, function (err, small) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // saved!
  });

  // or, for inserting large batches of documents
  Tank.insertMany([{ size: 'small' }], function(err) {

  });
```

But couldn't find any document inserted, nor Tank table created;

Comment: So you don't know if your connection to mongodb is successful am I right?

Comment: right, I am not sure what is going on with the concepts of routing, I put the code in a route, then in the app.js, both did not respond.

Comment: I can give you an example how I connect to my mongodb if you want.

Comment: sure! using mongoose preferably

Comment: try awaiting the mongoose.connect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I establish my connection like shown below:

```
require('dotenv').config();

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://myusername:' + process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD + '@myproject-z8wvn.mongodb.net/myproject?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/user', userRoute); //add the route
```

Then I created a `server.js` file to start the server using `nodemon`

After this I created my `User` schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Lastly create your routes (I have created a new file `user.js` in my case):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();
const User = require('../models/user');

router.delete('/getAllUsers', checkAccessToken, (req, res, next) => {

//do whatever you want here
console.log("getAllUsers is working! :)");
});
```

I hope this helps. :)